# How to limit the dimension of a 3D matix?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, data-analysis

I'm new to Matlab and currently working on a project which takes in frames of a tif video file(nxmx3010) and builds some 3D images for each 14 frames. . But now, the problem I'm facing is: When I take the first 14 frames of the file, the output 3D image(nxmx14) is good enough for me to do some manipulations, but then, the 3D image of the next 14 frames are having the starting frame:15 and ending frame:28, but, in the 3D image, the dimensions are being represented as nxmx28. The problem with this is, the new 3D matrix is having zero pixels in the 1-14 frames and the rest frames in the matrix are good.

My question is, how to not include the 1-14 empty frames while building 15-28 frame 3D matrix?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, construct the 3D matrix in a way that doesn't introduce this bug:P How are you constructing it? It's hard to debug invisible code.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw away the first 14 frames like so:

```
>> my_matrix = ones(10, 10, 28);
>> size(my_matrix)

ans =

    10    10    28

>> my_matrix(:,:,1:14) = [];   %% delete the first 14 "empty" frames
>> size(my_matrix)

ans =

    10    10    14
```

Comment: This method is fine for 14 frames but it takes a lot of time to execute for 3000 frames (like it is taking more than an hour)